# Getting Chid elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a code which is similar to the following snippet

```
 <div id="main">
  <div>
   <ul>
    <li>
      <table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
        <ul id="inner" > /* this ul has many nested children */</ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I would like to get all tags inside the "main" div and set them new id if they already has one. I have a javascript like one below

```
        var InfoMsg = "";
        var nodes = element.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) 
        {
            InfoMsg += nodes[i]
        }  
        alert(InfoMsg);
```

I get the following alert

```
 [object HTMLDivElement][object HTMLUListElement][object HTMLLIElement]
 [object HTMLTableElement][object HTMLTableSectionElement]
 [object HTMLTableRowElement][object HTMLTableCellElement]
 [object HTMLImageElement][object HTMLTableCellElement]
 [object HTMLTableCellElement]
```

Why does the inner ul  and its children are not getting retrieved by the  getElementsByTagName()  method, Or is there any other way to do so;

Note :
     At run time i will know only the "main" div id. All the children are dynamic and can run to any length.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm seeing the inner UListElement: http://jsfiddle.net/p9Snd/1/. Are you sure your DOM tree actually looks like what you've given at the time you query it?

Comment: Yes Dom tree look as the same as i given...only thing is the inner ul as further nested elements... Is there any other simple way to do it, ie. retrieving  all child elements including nested elements..

Comment: I have also tried retrieving child recursively using element.childNodes, but it also does the same, The inner ui and its child are not getting retreived..